# Looking for OpenCV android tutorial

Tags: android, opencv

does anyone now a good tutorial for implementing openCV in android?

I'm basically interested in affine\wrapper transformation

perspectiveTransform
warpPerspective

thanks!!!

Comment: Have you looked here? http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html?

Comment: Also, are you actually planning on implementing all of opencv on android? or just trying to get it running?

Comment: I guess a better flag for this would be a duplicate instead of closing.

Answer (score 2):

- You'll probably know [OpenCV's own Android tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html).
- The [Tegra Android Development Pack](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) by NVIDIA contains more than ten example Android projects which use OpenCV. In the `doc` folder there is some explanation, but not for all of them. You have to register to NVIDIA and apply as Tegra Developer, which means filling a form with general information.
- You need good knowledge of the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to create performant apps. Someone already [asked for JNI with Android Tutorials on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5659068/199048).