# Embedding camera readable data on an image

Tags: image, image-processing, image-recognition

I have a set of images on a data set and I want to create an application(on android initially) so that the application would be able to take an image and match it with an image on my data set. I tried using image recognition algorithms but I had very poor recognition chances. Is there any way to unobtrusively embed data on the image itself such that when a printed version of the image is scanned by the application, it would be able to extract the embedded data? I need some direction in this regard because I seem to be punching in the dark since I haven't worked on anything like this before.

Thanks

Comment: Some scheme including watermarking plus image recognition, is the only way to go. Image recognition hit rates vary, but they don't have to be "very poor". However, a complete answer is a *huge* problem as this is an area of active research (or worse, at the intersection of multiple areas of active research).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [OpenCV4Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), here is the [introductory](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html) tutorial. Following SO will give you some more- [Looking for OpenCV android tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368776/looking-for-opencv-android-tutorial#14375332)