# Android - calling a C module file

Tags: java, android, c

Okay, I have a compiled C module with some math routines in it.
Using the Android.mk file I would like to link this library and use it within JNI.
I want to use a java front end to call a C routine which in turn calls my C module....
Does anyone know of some good resources on Android.mk files and how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659068/jni-tutorial-for-android

Comment: The NDK includes several example projects. Start by looking at how they do things.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll take a look. One more questions: how do I go about linking two object files into one? Is this at all right: gfortran -c c_routine.o fortran_routine.o

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899740/android-ndk-tutorial-guide-for-beginners