# What is the full process to get c++ project to work in android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a C++ project:

**project structer**

```
projectname-
        |
         a_folder ->
                  |- file1.cpp,file2.h
         b_folder ->
                  |- file1.cpp,file2.h
         |
         c_folder ->
                  |
                  c.1_folder->
                             |- file1.cpp,file2.h
                  |
                   file1.cpp,file2.h
         ...
         ...             
         main.cpp
         project_interface.cpp
         project_interface.h
```

I read a lot on this subject but i don't really understand the flow of the process to make it work.

i manage to get the NDK example work and still after that its not really clear to me.

Also i want to get .a file from the c++ project not import the actually files into my android project. so [this example](http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/) not relevant.

**The big question is what is the full process to get c++ project to work in android ?**

** The job requirement is android app that use the c++ library to calculate stuff.

**i don't look for the all process to its details just the flow steps.

Comment: 1. How do you intend to run the C++ app? 2. You do realize that the .a file is for a specific architecture (CPU type)

Comment: Flow steps requires you to understand how you want to call the C++ project. Either you can do it via the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350283/any-way-to-run-shell-commands-on-android-programmatically or build a Java NDK API which will call the C++ code.

Comment: @morrison With NDK api.

Comment: A bit old but may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659068/jni-tutorial-for-android If you search on 'Java JNI tutorial' the interface is the same on Android as on a PC - its just packaging the binary into the app that is different.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is completely c++. The NDK provides a way to compile c++ into your java android app but we can use its compiler to create a cross compiler for android.

1.) Download and install the android SDK and NDK. Install them to a directory within your path.

2.) Compile your c++ using the cross compiler provided with the NDK.

3.) ADB push "binary" "Where ever on the phone you want"

4.) You can run the c++ on the phone

Note: You need a rooted phone to do this kind of development.

In the case that your trying to use the NDK to use the c++ within a native java app. Then the steps are a little different.

1.) Download NDK and SDK

2.) Create android app in java.

3.) Use NDK to build c++ within a project. (There are some nice tutorials for this step)

4.) Call the c++ methods as if they were java methods.

5.) Build the java app normally.

Comment: I think you're missing a step like - create Android app to call C++. Unless you are talking about a rooted device.

Comment: It looks like the OP isn't trying to add c++ to a android app but instead compile one from scratch. Given the main.cpp. Ill add an edit though just in case.

Comment: The part of the c++ project is to calculate massive data. to preview the data on a device i developing native android app(java).

Comment: I'm looking for sections 3 and 4 step. this is the part that not really clear.

Comment: Im sorry. One could write a book about the steps for 3 and 4. I know we don't normally post links but I think this tutorial will help you alot. http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html